# extracts data from json to CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, opensea

I'm working with opensea response file json, try to get info about nft

json file
https://paste.pythondiscord.com/yazaxipiwe
full json file
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/303906514266226689/1028843885906116658/opensea.json

im getting problems with extracting traits data,
traits have daynamic data like some have null traits data and some have 4 to 8 traits data

how to extract like this traits

```
name    link    traits_type(eye)    traits_type(fur)    traits_type(mouth)
APE 0   https://lh3.google.com  3d eye  red open-mouth 
APE1    https://lh3.google.com  brown   robot   moster
APE2    https://lh3.google.com  white   green   big teeth 
APE3    https://lh3.google.com  monster eye brown   sharp teeth
```

[CSV link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYs6a.jpg)

code

```
file = json.load(open('opensea.json'))
name.append(file['name'])
link.append(file['image_url'])
```

but how do get traits data?

Comment: you may try to use [pandas.json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) or you will have to write `for`-loop to create rows.

Comment: @furas no use I have tried
of pandas.json_normalize()

Comment: @furas can u tell in more detail how write for loop to create rows

Comment: `for item in file['traits']: print( item['trait_type'], item['value'] )` . And if you want many types in row then first you would have to create dictionary with values `{type: value, ...}` and after `for`-loop use it to create row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may need to use `for`-loop to convert it to dictionary with `{type:value}`

```
data = {}
for item in file['traits']: 
    key = item['trait_type']
    value = item['value'] 

    data[key] = value

    print(key, value)
```

and later you can create row (using `.get()` you can set default value when item doesn't exist)

```
row = [
     file['name'], 
     file['image_url'], 
     data.get('Eye', ''), 
     data.get('Fur', ''), 
     data.get('Mouth', '')
]
```

and add to list

```
all_rows.append(row)
```

and later convert all to DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=['name', 'link', 'traits_type(eye)', 'traits_type(fur)', 'traits_type(mouth)']
```

---

```
import json
import pandas as pd

file = json.load(open('opensea.json'))

print(file.keys())

all_rows = []

for asset in file['assets']:
    data = {}
    for item in asset['traits']: 
        key = item['trait_type']
        value = item['value'] 

        data[key] = value

        #print(key, value)
        
    row = [
        asset['name'],
        asset['image_url'],
        data.get('Fur', ''),
        data.get('Eyes', ''),
        data.get('Mouth', '')
    ]
    all_rows.append(row)
    
for item in all_rows:
    print(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=['name', 'url', 'fur', 'eyes', 'mouth'])
print(df[['name', 'fur', 'eyes', 'mouth']])
```

Result:

```
    name           fur         eyes                     mouth
0   None         Robot       X Eyes                Discomfort
1   None         Robot   Blue Beams                      Grin
2   None         Robot           3d           Bored Cigarette
3   None       Cheetah        Bored                Tongue Out
4   None  Golden Brown       Closed                 Phoneme L
5   None         Brown       X Eyes               Dumbfounded
6   None         Cream        Crazy                     Bored
7   None  Golden Brown        Angry                     Bored
8   None        Zombie        Robot                     Bored
9   None         Brown       Sleepy                Small Grin
10  None           Dmt     Eyepatch                     Bored
11  None    Dark Brown    Bloodshot  Bored Unshaven Cigarette
# ...
```

Comment: I see your blog on pillow library it was impressive. i want Little help with getting list of rbg in grayscale image using pillow where RGB list has to be look like [R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, B2,..., Rn, Gn, Bn]

Comment: you can convert `pillow` to `numpy.array` and flatten it - `np.array(pillow_image).flatten()`

Comment: sir one more question is there any way to convert or remove round corner (edges) of images to square corner ?

Comment: the simplest idea: crop image. You can use `pillow` to crop it or you can slice `numpy.array` - like `arr[y1:y2, x1:x2]`. Eventually you can try to use `Computer Vision` (module `OpenCV`) to add missing pixels using [inpainting](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need 1 trait only, you can use

```py
[i['value'] for i in file['traits'] if i['trait_type'] == 'the trait type you need'][0]
```

which you use a for loop `for i in file['traits']`
to create a list that includes `i['value']` if `i['trait_type']` is the one you need. Then take the first item in the list with `[0]`

Otherwise, consider

```py
for i in file['traits']:
    if i['trait_type'] == 'the_trait':
        list_for_the_trait.append(i['value'])
    ...
```